# Laravel 4: pass value from filter to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

is there anyway to pass variable value from filter to Controller,

I tried return this value but it break controller execution:

```
Route::filter('is_admin', function()
{
    $data = DB::select(
        'select level from users where user_id = ? limit 1',
        array(Auth::user()->id)
    );

    if($data[0]->level > 5)
    {
            return 'not authorized';
    }

    //return level here 
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: @Jerodev no,but return data from laravel filter, prevents execution of controller

Comment: Filter should return `true`/`false`. Its not good idea to passing variables from filter to controller. Explain what you want to archieve and we will try to find another solition.

Comment: @Kasyx I want to return administration level of current user (if less than 5 return "not authorized" else go back to controller with administration level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your filter into:

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->level > 5)
    {
         return 'not authorized'; 
    }
});
```

and in all paths protected by this filter you can simply use:

```
echo Auth::user()->name;
```

or

```
$user = Auth::user();
echo $user->name;
echo $user->level;
```

so you don't need to pass any data from filter to controllers or views. You can use it in controllers, you can use it in other models, you can use it even in view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to passing variable from filter to controller. Its also bad idea.
I see you want to get level from current user. Following code inside your controller should be enought:

```
$level = Auth::user()->level;
```

Also you can make your filter much simplier:

```
Route::filter('is_admin', function()
{
    $level = Auth::user()->level;

    if($level > 5)
    {
            return 'not authorized';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to pass the value over. I see you're using `Auth::user()` so you probably have a `User` model that associated with the table `users`.

You should be able to just write:

```
Auth::user()->level
```

(in your filter as well as in your controller)